# SharePoint List flow - how to format link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, metadata, flow

I am using SharePoint Online and I have a list for which I am creating a flow.  This flow is connected to a document library so that when a new doc is created it is added to the list.  We have a column in the list that links to the document.  At present, the link is displayed in the column as the full URL, which is messy and long.  Basically, it doesn't look pretty and might seem odd to people unfamiliar with the system.  In flow, there has to be a way to format the link.  In the field in the flow action, I put the dynamic data 'Link to item' which inputs the URL.  I would like to have something where I use the dynamic data for 'Title' to be displayed but it uses the URL as the link.  So, when an employee is looking at the list, they only see the title of the list, but when they click it, it opens up the document.

I should probably note that in the list, at present, the column that holds the URL is set to be a hyperlink field.

Thanks everyone!